# Use of ROWID in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE (ROWID,0) IN (SELECT ROWID, MOD(ROWNUM,4)
FROM emp);
```

What is use of Rowid,0 in above query ? i checked the documentation but could not find details about this.

Comment: It get every fourth row but to get to the point in searches for rowid in rowid and 0 in MOD(rownum,4)

Comment: i am not getting what (ROWID,0) in where clause means ? AS far as i remember Rowid is not a function.

Comment: The `IN` operator can also be applied onto tuples (pairs in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MOD(1,4) FROM dual returns 1
SELECT MOD(2,4) FROM dual returns 2
SELECT MOD(3,4) FROM dual returns 3
SELECT MOD(4,4) FROM dual returns 0
```

So the above query selects every row which returns the value 0 for the MOD functions, which is basically the 4th row.